How to filter fields in object that I have in type "Todo"
I want to have only two field in object returned from API.
How to filter out these two fields, leaving others out?
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';


type Todo = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
};

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

const fetchData = async (): Promise<any> => {

    const response: AxiosResponse = await axios.get<Todo>(url);
    const responseData: Todo = response.data;
    return responseData;
};

fetchData().then((r) => {
  console.log(r);
});```


Is this question about axios? If so you should tag it as such. If not, please [edit] the code not to make reference to it. The code you post should be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and quickly get to work, without dependencies on third party libraries (unless the question is about those libraries).
